# Разлогиниться во всех вкладках

Tags: php, сессия

Делаю небольшое приложение на php, в котором есть авторизация, login происходит при помощи сессий, проблема в том, что если открыть две вкладки с выполненной авторизацией, то если в одной из них сделать logout, то в другой вкладке я смогу набрать текст, и он сохранится, хотя это действие доступно только авторизированному пользователю, как это исправить?
Вот код для logout:

```
function action_logout() {
        setcookie ("PHPSESSID", "", time() - 3600, '/');
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
        header('Location:/');
    }
```

Comment: Ну значит код сохранения текста забывает проверять статус авторизации

Answer (score 0):

*Ответ взят из комментария @andreymal:*

> Код сохранения текста забывает проверять статус авторизации